# General formula for the following operator?

Tags: operator-theory, closed-form, algebra-precalculus

I am looking for a general formula for the following linear operator $T_n[f]$.

$$T_0[f]=1$$

$$T_1[f]=\pi f(x)-\frac12$$

$$T_2[f]=2i\pi f'(x)-\pi f(x) +\frac16$$

etc.

In general, $T_n[f]$ is equal to $B_{n+1}(x)$ (Bernoulli polynomials) where each $x^k$ is replaced with $k i^{k-1}\pi f^{(k-1)}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(f^{(k)}(s)\right)=(-1)^k x^k (\mathcal{L}^{-1}f)(x)$ we have

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} T_n[f] = \sum k i^{k-1}\pi (-1)^{k-1} x^{k-1}(\mathcal{L}^{-1}f)(x)$$
and 
$$ T_n[f]=\pi\mathcal{L}\left[B_{n+1}'(-ix)\cdot(\mathcal{L}^{-1} f)(x)\right]. $$

Comment: What is $\mathcal{L}$? Laplace transform?

Comment: @Anixx: exactly.

Comment: Simply great!!!

Comment: By the way, what changes if $f(x)=\delta(x)$?

Comment: @Anixx: in such a case it is better to apply the same manipulations with the Laplace transform being replaced by the Fourier transform, since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\delta$ is not well-defined. You should get $$ T_n[f]=\pi\mathcal{F}\left[B_{n+1}'(x)\cdot(\mathcal{F}^{-1}f)(x)\right]$$

Comment: So, it will be all the same, but with Fourier symbol, yes?

Comment: $$T_n[f]=\mathcal{F}\left[B_{n+1}'(-ix)\right]$$?

Comment: That depends on the normalization assumed for $\mathcal{F}$, but $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\delta$ is a constant, I agree.

Comment: Oh I fixed for the correct normalization. In the desired normalization the transform of $1$ is $\pi\delta(x)$

Comment: It turns something like $T_n[f]=\mathcal{F}\left[nB_{n}(-ix)\right]$

Comment: @Anixx: more likely $T_n[\delta]=n\mathcal{F}[B_n(x)].$

Comment: Thanks! This is even simplier!

Comment: Well, something is wrong... For $n=1$ your formula gives $-1/2 \pi \delta(x)$ while the correct answer should be $\pi\delta(x)-1/2$

Comment: Okay, I found the correct formula, it is very simple: $B_n+n\int_0^\infty B_{n-1}(x)$